# $f(x,y)$ in polar coordinates

Tags: analysis, inverse

So, I have $ f(x,y) = (x^2-y^2, 2xy) $, 
which is a local $\mathcal C^1$ isomorphism in  $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$.

I have to write this function in polar coordinates:

$$f(x,y) = f(r\cos\phi, r\sin\phi).$$

My beginnings:
I know that

$$df(r, \phi) = 
\cos\phi -r\sin\phi 
\sin\phi r\cos\phi.$$

But I really have no clue how to work this one out. It is a single exercise of this kind in my book; so, I probably  don't need it for the test, but I would like to know.

Comment: Just plug in $r\cos \phi$ and $r\sin\phi$ for $x$ and $y$ respectively.  Note that trig identities will allow you to simplify your result.

Comment: As @Aaron suggested $f(r,\theta)$ can be obtained by replacing $x$ with $r\cos{\theta}$ and $y$ with $r\sin{\theta}$

Answer (score 1):

In polar coordinates, we have $(x,y) =(r\cos\phi, r\sin\phi)$ as you said. Therefore, 
$f(x,y) = (x^2-y^2, 2xy)$ can be rewritten as 
$$f(x,y) =f(r\cos\phi, r\sin\phi)= \big((r\cos\phi)^2-(r\sin\phi)^2, 2(r\cos\phi)(r\sin\phi)\big)$$
$$=\big(r^2(\cos^2\phi-\sin^2\phi),r^2(2\sin\phi\cos\phi)\big)=\big(r^2\cos(2\phi),r^2\sin(2\phi)\big).$$

Comment: thanx much paul, i came to similar solution. Would that mean that the function is bijective only from (0,8)x(0, 2Pi) because of ϕ being periodic?